# Is the system stiff or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let the problem of initial values

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y_1'(t)=-0.5y_1(t)+0.501 y_2(t), t \in [0,10^3]\\ 
y_2'(t)=0.501y_1(t)-0.5y_2(t) \\
y_1(0)=1.1 \\
y_2(0)-0.9 
\end{matrix}\right.  \\ $

The question is if the system is stiff.

$$A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-0.5 & 0.501\\ 
0.501 & -0.5 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$

$$y'=Ay$$

where $y'=\binom{y_1'}{y_2'}, \ y=\binom{y_1}{y_2}$.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-1.001, \lambda_2=0.001$.

According the assistant of the professor, since it holds that $|\lambda_1|>> |\lambda_2|$ we deduce that the system is stiff.

But I found the following in my book:

> Stiff systems are systems of the form $x'=Ax$ for ehich there are eigenvalues $\lambda_{\mu}$ and $\lambda_{\nu}$ of $A$, with negative real part, such that $|Re{\lambda_{\mu}}|>>|Re{\lambda_{\nu}}|$.

So since we found only one negative and one positive eigenvalue, don't we conclude that the system isn't stiff? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The system is stiff if you can divide its eigenvalues into two sets:  the soft part ($|\lambda_i| \leq \ell$) and the stiff part ($\operatorname{Re} \lambda_i < -L$) with some $L \gg \ell$.
That's eaxctly your case, with $L = 1$ and $\ell = 0.001$. 
[image: Spectrum of a stiff system].

P.S. Having eigenvalues of different magnitude, e.g. $|\lambda_2| \gg |\lambda_1|$ is not sufficient for system to be stiff. Actually it covers also *unstable* systems.